# how to schedule a job in hadoop which consists of impala queries?

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, hue

in oozie there are actions provided for hive and shell scripts etc. so is there any way by which we can schedule a job(which consists of impala queries) without using shell action and java?
or is there any solution like hue?
please suggest

Comment: Oozie doesn't have impala action. You can either use shell action or java action(jdbc) that invokes the impala queries.

Comment: thanks to reply Amal.
can you suggest any UI like HUE to perform the same?

Comment: You can use oozie through hue. The shell action for impala will create issues only if the cluster is kerberized.